# Xcode 4.2 "Run on device" performance with large app caches

Tags: ios, xcode

I've developed an iOS 5 application with a rather large cache stored in **/Library/Caches**.  I've noticed that running the app on an actual ipad is getting *very* slow.  As in 5 minutes or so just to launch the application.  Without Xcode, the application launches quickly.  There seems to be a correlation between the size of the cache and the amount of time it takes to run the application, as the application starts quickly with a minimal cache.

I'm assuming that Xcode is making a backup or something silly like this.  Has anyone else experienced this, and if so is there a workaround?

**EDIT:** (for clarity)

The structure of **/Library/Caches/** is:

```
./big_ass_image1.png
./big_ass_image2.png
...
./big_ass_imageN.png
```

I simply read them in with coregraphics at a later time.  The issue is the speed at which Xcode actually *runs* my app on the ipad.  It's upwards of 4 minutes, which makes on device development very difficult.  I would use the simulator, but it's precisely these big data sets that need to be tested on device.

**EDIT:** (how the files get there)

The files get into the cache via downloading. And sadly, there's no way to limit the cache size (at least not at the 2 gigabyte level).

Comment: How are you storing the cache? Is it an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, perhaps? If so, writing and reading a very large object like this can take a long time and slow things down. I've run into this myself. I switched to CoreData in one project and it helped improve startup performance dramatically because I didn't actually have to read the whole cache into memory at startup.

Comment: I should mention this is a file cache in /Library/Caches.  Like images, data, etc.  Mostly images... potentially gigs of them.

Comment: Right, you said that. So how are you storing the data? What is it you are writing out and reading in? The sheer size of the object you are reading, if it represents the entire cache, could be the problem.

Comment: It's file based. E.g. I load the images with CoreGraphics.  The application speed isn't a problem, it's just the wait time to actually RUN the app on Xcode that's the issue ;)

Comment: Have you run it the app with Instruments and the Time Profiler to see where, exactly, the most time is being spent? That will be quite helpful in determining what you need to do.

Comment: Launching time profiler takes 10 minutes ;)  The problem is in Xcode, before the app ever launches.  If I remove the cache from the device, time profiler launches immediately!  Thanks for keeping this dialog going, I do appreciate the trouble shooting.

Comment: How do you get the files into the cache in the first place? Are they stored in the application bundle?

Comment: The files get to the cache via downloading (normally not a full 2 gigs at a time, but sometimes).  I use ASIHttpRequest.  Updating the issues.

Comment: Does the app take a long time to launch if you don't launch it with XCode?

Comment: No, not at all. Also if you do enterprise distribution (via the web) it's not slow to upgrade regardless of the cache.